# Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, view, compilation, controller, laravel-blade

I download the project partially from the server that we had hosted.
and while runing it in local it shows this error
Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive()
I don't know what exactly is happening?
what cause this error.

Comment: Why would you only download a portion of the project?

Comment: whole project is nearly 1 gb and could not be downloaded.
i have tried mre than 10 times but it said couold not be downloaded when reached 100 mb

Comment: Okay. Lol. Well, the `directive` method is new to Laravel 5.1 so if you are running 5.0, you will need to update it.